# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE при парсинге

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Не могу понять, в чем проблема. Есть код, он рабочий, но при работе браузер выдает эту ошибку. Сидел искал полдня и ничего, так и не нашел причину.

Вот вам собственно код:

Файл function.php

```
function html_url($url) {  
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
$data = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);  
return $data;  
}
```

Файл index.php

```
    include 'simple_html_dom.php';  
include 'function.php';  
$file = fopen('logtxt.txt', 'w+');  
$html = str_get_html(html_url('http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en'));  
$hfer = $html->find('.catfiltertopitem a');  
    foreach ($hfer as $dan) {  
            if (html_url('http://www.digikey.com'.$dan->href) == true){  
                echo 'Соединение установлено';  
            }else{  
                echo 'Ошибка соединения';  
            }  
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Данную проблему решил очень просто:

1. Правка файла php.ini

   ```
   memory_limit = 512M  
   upload_max_filesize = 512M
   ```
2. В начале скрипта добавил строку:

   ```
   ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
   ```

Но на английском форуме читал что, `ini_set` это не выход!